# HNMR spectroscopy mono-carboxylated acid

Tags: organic-chemistry, spectroscopy, nmr-spectroscopy

During lab, I have done following reaction:
[image]

I did HNMR of the product, to be certain if the product really was formed.

The HNMR gave following results:

[image]

And looked like this:

[image]

So my question is: has the reaction succesfully taken place?
I know that the peaks between 6.5 and 8 ppm represent protons, attached to an aromatic molecule. But there are only four peaks between 6.5 and 8 ppm, instead of 5 (the amount that I expected). At 3.89 ppm, there is a singlet with 5 protons present, which is weird because I expected only 1 singlet with 3 protons. The 7 protons at 1.53 ppm I don't understand at all.

Please help me out.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have the NMR spectrum of the starting material?

Comment: No, I unfortunately do not .

Comment: I think your questions should rather be "what has happened *instead* of the reaction intended?"

Comment: How did you work up this reaction? Have you got a fifth proton under the CDCl3 signal at 7.25?